# True or false: Least Squares is Statistics Independent?

Tags: least-squares

If one has a vector of data, $Y$, and a vector of covariate $X$, supposed to be related linearly, the least squares estimate is $\hat{\beta} = (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}Y$. This is simply the orthogonal projection of the $Y$ vector onto the column space of $X$, so it is a geometric solution to a vector spaces problem: basically finding the closest vector in the column space to the data vector in terms of Euclidean distance. So what assumptions cause the statistical implications to arise?

Comment: To what "statistical implications" are you referring?

Comment: if $Y _i =X\beta+ \varepsilon_i$ where $\varepsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, the standard error of the regression (estimate of the error variance) is the MSE. Also, that $\hat{\beta}$ is an estimator of $\beta$, with a covariance matrix.

Comment: The only assumptions needed for those implications are that the multivariate distribution of the $\varepsilon_i$ has zero mean and a covariance which is a finite multiple of the identity matrix.  Normality is not needed for any of those particular implications. Other implications will require more or fewer assumptions. This is why it's essential that you edit this question to specify precisely which implications you are concerned with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True. Let me use the simple example of calculating an average of a sample $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^n$, which is a special case of the above when $X$ is a vector of ones. Then, $\hat\beta$ is equal to the sample average $\bar y$.

Now, of course, $\bar y$ can be computed without any assumptions (what you call "statistics independent"), as merely a descriptive statistic.

But, "no result without assumptions" - if you want your sample average to be representative for some feature of an underlying distribution/population, you need to assume something for example about the sampling process that generated $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^n$.

For example, if the sample is a random sample from a population with expected value $\mu$, it is well-known that $\bar y$ is an unbiased estimator of $\mu$:

$$
E(\bar y)=E\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_iY_i\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_iE(Y_i)=\frac{n}{n}E(Y_i)=\mu,
$$
as random sampling implies that each $Y_i$ has the same distribution, hence same expected value.

Comment: And the assumption about what sampling process generated $\left\{y_i\right\}^{n}_{i=1}$ comes from the assumption about the error variance, $\varepsilon$?

Comment: Yes, about assumptions on $\epsilon$ if you write the model underlying my example as $Y_i=\mu+\epsilon_i$ where $\epsilon_i\sim iid (0,\sigma^2)$ So not only the variance! (In fact, we could get results on unbiasedness with weaker assumptions, mean zero of $\epsilon_i$ would suffice.

Comment: So, does this fact extend to nonlinear models? Say I have a quantity of interest, $Y$, that is supposed to have underlying model $Y_i = g(X|\theta) + \varepsilon_i$. I suspect that $g(X|\theta) = \mu$ is a special case and that nonlinear models are more complicated orthogonal projections first, with attached statistical assumptions later.